# How to stop BackgroundWorker and exit from all my loops

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an application that uses a BackgroundWorker to play files from a list. After I press the Stop button, the file that is running will stop running but will not stop the next file in the list from playing.

The variables in the code are:
playCount - how many files I have run, numberOfLoops - how much loops I want to run, Loops mean all the files in my list box (listBoxFiles), and myClass.playCapture - what runs in the background.

```
while (playCount < numberOfLoops && bContinuePlay && ifContinue) //play the file
{
    for (int i = 0; (i < listBoxFiles.Items.Count) && bContinuePlay && ifContinue; i++)
    {
        string path = (string)listBoxFiles.Items[i];
        myClass = new myClass(path, playSpeed);
        myClass.evePacketProgress += new myClass.dlgPacketProgress(
            (progressCount) =>
            {
                myClass._fileSelectedIndex = i;
                bgWoSingle.ReportProgress(progressCount, myClass);
            });

        if (selectedAdapter != null)
        {
            bContinuePlay = myClass.playCapture(selectedAdapter._packetDevice); //here the BackgroundWorker running
        }
    }

    playCount++;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you just need to use the [CancelAsync Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.cancelasync.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you maybe forgot to set bContinuePlay or ifContinue to false in your stop code. If this is not the case, please provide more code. (Where you start and stop the process)

Comment: I would still suggest looking into the CancelAsync Method from my answer, as this could clean up some of your code.

Comment: when call CancelAsync Method it will delete the BackgroundWorker running ? what about all others that should open after the one who cancel ?

Comment: @user1269592, has this fixed the problem or does it still not work?